# How to add text editor in the admin form and save data to the database in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, uicomponent, magento2.4

```
<fieldset name="content">
        <settings>
            <label>Wysiwyg Content</label>
        </settings>
        <field name="wysiwyg_example" sortOrder="50" formElement="wysiwyg">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label>Content</label>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <wysiwyg>
                    <settings>
                        <rows>8</rows>
                        <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                    </settings>
                </wysiwyg>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
```

I added this UI element to my custom form, but the total page builder is coming. But I don't need a total pagebuilder I need only a text editor.

How can I add only text editor from pagebuilder in my form and how to add text editor data to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this field config options:

```
<field name="wysiwyg_example">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
            <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
            <!-- other items -->
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: thanks @slava it is working fine